# Is there a way to retrieve the value of a promise or observable in an external variable?

Tags: angular, asynchronous, promise

I've read all about `.then()` and I understand how it works, and it is actually working in my current implementation and giving me the value I'm looking for.

```
async getDay() {
    try {
      let ref = this.db.getDay(this.dateFirebase);
      ref.then(out => {
        out.get().then(inner => {
          console.log(inner.data());
        })
      })
    } catch (err) {
      console.log(err);
    }
  }
```

`inner.data()` gives me the exact object I need to work with, but I'm unable to use it anywhere else in the component, can't assign it to any component properties and can't get it outside of this scope.

What I'm trying to do right now is retrieve `inner.data()`, which is a basic object containing a few fields, and then display it in a HTML template and use it later on for various other purposes. If I want to get the object from inside of it, can I only do that by calling `.then()` every single time or is there a way to store it in a local variable?

If I do something like:

```
out.get().then(inner => {
          console.log(inner.data());
          this.day = inner.data();
          console.log(this.day);
   })
```

I can actually see the data, then I set the component property `day` to the data, then print out the property and see the data recorded in it. In another method, I've got a setInterval function running that's printing out the `day` property, which continually prints `undefined`, even after I've set the property successfully.

It seems like no matter what I do, the value inside the promise can't be used outside of it, even after it's already retrieved. What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: The issue is one of timing.  First, you can only get a value from a promise with `await` or `.then()`.  Second, the ONLY place you know that the value is actually available is inside the `.then()` handler or after the `await` or in some function you call from there and pass it to.  So, while you can assign it to an object property or a higher scoped variable, it generally isn't very useful because outside code has no idea WHEN the property or variable now contains the useful value.  So, just use it with `.then()` or `await` and learn to code that way.

Comment: I'm still struggling to understand how you'd use this value in a HTML template. I changed my implementation a bit, so `this.day` stores the promise returned by `out.get()` and then tried to use the `async` pipe in an `ngFor` loop, but nothing prints. There are no template errors, but my `<p>` tags are still empty. I think I'm using the pipe properly: `<div *ngFor="let item of day | async">`.

Comment: You have to get the asynchronous value and ONLY when you have it and any other asynchronous values you need, then and only then render your template.  Most likely you have to trigger rendering of your template in a `.then()` or after an `await` so you know you have the value you need before rendering.

Answer (score 1):

Use the await so you can wait for each promise to resolve.

```
function async getDay() {
    try {
      const out await this.db.getDay(this.dateFirebase);
      const inner = await out.get()
      return inner.data();
    } catch (err) {
      console.log(err);
    }
  }
```

then to call this else where:

```
getDay().then(day => this.day = day)
// or 
this.day = await this.getDay()
```